# How to integrate HTML in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Does anyone know how to integrate HTML/CSS in Smarty template? I am new to Smarty Template engine. Please suggest, as much needed help here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must upload the "libs" folder.

Next, you must construct your index.php:

```
require('libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->setTemplateDir('templates');
$smarty->setCompileDir('templates_c');
$smarty->setCacheDir('cache');
$smarty->setConfigDir('configs');
$template="home.tpl";
$smarty->display($template);
```

Now, you must make a few directories.
Start out with making these directories:

```
templates
templates_c
cache
configs
```

After those are all made, you're ready to make your template. This will be saved into the "templates" directory. Name it `home.tpl`
Your template will be just like normal HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, hit your index page. It should show your template just like you would expect.